# StatusBar grey when opening app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-styles, android-statusbar

In my Application written with Xamarin.Android. When the App is just opening (the time the application takes to open) the status bar color is grey.

[image]

But when the application finally runs, the status looks has the dark blue color I assigned in Styles.xml.

[image]

This is the Theme

```xml
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Base.Theme.DesignDemo"></style>

  <style name="Theme.DesignDemo2" parent="Base.Theme.DesignDemo"></style>

  <style name="Base.Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
  </style>

  <style name="Theme.DesignDemo.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

  <style name="Theme.DesignDemo.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

and `Styles.xml V-21`

```xml
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.DesignDemo" parent="Base.Theme.DesignDemo">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/primary_dark</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

and the `colors.xml`

```xml
<resources>
  <color name="colorPrimary">#002868</color>
  <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#002053</color>
  <color name="colorPrimaryRed">#AF0505</color> <!--BF0A30-->
  <color name="colorAccent">#b2dfdb</color>
  <color name="colorWhite">#FFF</color>
</resources>
```

If you look at WhatsApp for instance, even it takes a few seconds to open, but uses the colors they set and not a default grey color.

Comment: Do you have a splash screen? If so what is the style for it - sometimes it's different as it is styled with a drawable as the background for example.

Comment: Does this issue happen whenever your app get launched or just the first time your app get installed and opened?

Comment: Ho, I have a Intro, I used the nugged AppIntro, but I assign the theme in the Intro Activity:

[Activity(Label = "IntroApp", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/Theme.DesignDemo")]
    public class IntroApp : AppIntro.AppIntro2

Comment: Did you resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

Your styles look perfectly fine. However, you might have missed one thing. What you probably have done is to simply assign the theme to the Activities that you want styled, maybe in this case you only have one, because you are playing around.

This is fine. However, setting the style only on your Activities means that when the App starts it just uses some default style based on the Android API version and system style.

You obviously want to style it so the look in your app is consistent, right?

To do so, you need simply to open up the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and locate the `Application` node. In here you need, similarly to your Activity, add a theme attribute. This could look something like:

```xml
<application android:theme="@style/Theme.DesignDemo" android:label="@string/appname" android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon_launcher">
```

This will set the style application wide, and you can override it per Activity if you want different styles on different Activities.

Comment: I did it, but It is still the same detail u.u